# Why do I get an AttributeError when calling the method?

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-class

In this code, there's a `Person` class that has an attribute `name`, which gets set when constructing the object.

It should do:

1. When an instance of the class is created, the attribute gets set correctly
2. When the `greeting()` method is called, the greeting states the assigned name.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greeting(self):
        # Should return "hi, my name is " followed by the name of the Person.
        return "hi, my name is {}".format(self.name) 
    
# Create a new instance with a name of your choice
some_person = "xyz"  
# Call the greeting method
print(some_person.greeting())
```

It returned the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'greeting'

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend that you go through the docs before asking your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just setting the variable to a string, not a `Person` class. This would make a `Person` with a name of `xyz` instead.

```
some_person = Person("xyz")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `some_person` variable is an instance of `str` object. Which does not have the attribute `greeting`.

Your class `Person` should be instanced with `name` variable before you can use  `greeting`:

```
some_person = Person(“xyz”)
print(some_person.greeting())
# "hi, my name is xyz”
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greeting(self):
        # Should return "hi, my name is " followed by the name of the Person.
        print("hi, my name is ",self.name)

# Create a new instance with a name of your choice
some_person = Person("Honey")

# Call the greeting method
print(some_person.greeting())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Use str method instead of greeting() method
def __str__(self):
    # Should return "hi, my name is " followed by the name of the Person.
    return "hi, my name is {}".format(self.name) 
some_person = Person("xyz")  
# Call the __str__ method
print(some_person)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
def greeting(self):
    # Should return "hi, my name is " followed by the name of the Person.
    return name

# Create a new instance with a name of your choice
some_person = Person("Bob")
# Call the greeting method
print(f"hi, my name is {some_person.name}")
```

Comment: The question was related to the object initialization. Your code doesn't answer the question and has a missing "self", causing an attribute error when greeting() is called

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greeting(self):
        # Should return "hi, my name is " followed by the name of the Person.
        return name

# Create a new instance with a name of your choice
some_person =  Person("XYZ")
# Call the greeting method
print(f"hi, my name is {some_person.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Class Person:
   def_init_(self,name):
      self.name = name
   def greeting(self):
      return name
Some_person = Person("Aisha")
Print("hi, my name is {}".format(Some_person.name))
```

Output: should print `'hi, my name is Aisha'`

Comment: Hello, to what extent is this answer complementing the already-accepted answer?